# Magento - Separate contact forms

Tags: magento, contact-form

I'm working on a website where the client needs to have multiple separate contact forms (one for contact, one for "request a quote", another couple for stuff like that).

I've already managed to create another contact form with additional fields, but it was the contact one, so the fields were only name, email, subject and message.

Now I've got the "skeleton" of the others, but my question is: is there a way to take advantage of the "Contact" backend to send emails?  Or do I need to have another controller to manage them?

If so, can you show me some links or piece of code to start off with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea man it should be easy to plugin into the email function. Can you specify if you wish to use an existing template or a custom one to send out emails?

Comment: I'd use a custom template (I've added another couple of fields such as address, telephone, description, year of production etc.).

Answer (score 4):

To do what you want, a custom controller is necessary to pass the POST data.

If you examine `\app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php` on line ~62 you'll find `postAction()` which is called by `indexAction()` - the default action of the controller.

This is the method that is collecting the passed POST parameters and using the `core/email_template` model to send off the e-mail. I'd use this code as a reference for your controller.

Be sure you put it all in your own module as always with functionality additions.

To know what you can and cannot pass to the `core/email_template` model, take a look at `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php`. It's got loads of documentation in there for you.

Heck, it's even got example code!

```
// Loading of template
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
   ->load(Mage::getStoreConfig('path_to_email_template_id_config'));
$variables = array(
   'someObject' => Mage::getSingleton('some_model')
   'someString' => 'Some string value'
);
$emailTemplate->send('some@domain.com', 'Name Of User', $variables);
```

In particular take a look at line ~371, where it passes the variables you set to the layout-specified e-mail template.

```
/**
 * Send mail to recipient
 *
 * @param   array|string       $email        E-mail(s)
 * @param   array|string|null  $name         receiver name(s)
 * @param   array              $variables    template variables
 * @return  boolean
 **/
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
```

Magento is doing the same thing that you'd do with any contact form on a plain old PHP form processor. It just delegates everything out to models like the one above so you don't have to do so much work re-inventing the wheel, as it were. Just a new controller to accept the parameters in the POST data.

Feel free to follow up and I'll update the answer to help you where I can!

Here's a concise list of things you'll need to make this happen:

- A custom controller to accept the form(s) POST data and pass it to the `core/email_template` model.
- A custom form in the front-end pointing to your controller URL (already done!)
- A custom e-mail template for the `core/email_template` to use to display the data in the e-mail the recipient sees.